# Plotly map not rendering when using date format in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm working on a Covid EDA practice project and I'm trying to create a map that shows cases over time.
In the data provided by Our World in Data, the date is a string. If I leave the date as string Plotly properly renders the map, but the dates are out of order. I used the following code:

```
cot_map <- country %>% 
  select(location, date, total_cases)

plot_geo(cot_map,
         locationmode = "country names",
         format = ~date) %>% 
  add_trace(locations = ~location,
            z = ~total_cases,
            zmin = 0,
            zmax = 51000000,
            color = ~total_cases)
```

If I coerce the date into date type, it does change into date in the data frame, but Plotly renders a blank box (not even the legend), both in the Viewer and if I open it in a new window. This is the code I used:

```
cot_map <- country %>% 
  select(location, date, total_cases)
cot_map$date <- as.Date(cot_map$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

plot_geo(cot_map,
         locationmode = "country names",
         format = ~date) %>% 
  add_trace(locations = ~location,
            z = ~total_cases,
            zmin = 0,
            zmax = 51000000,
            color = ~total_cases)
```

I also tried converting to date and POSIX using both base R and the `lubridate` package but nothing worked. I've scoured the web but failed to find a solution. I'm using the latest version of RStudio Desktop. Has anyone encountered this before?

**EDIT**

This is a tiny subset of the dataframe I used, which contains around 130k observations on most countries.

```
  iso_code    location       date total_cases
1      AFG Afghanistan 24/02/2020           5
2      AFG Afghanistan 25/02/2020           5
3      AFG Afghanistan 26/02/2020           5
4      AFG Afghanistan 27/02/2020           5
5      AFG Afghanistan 28/02/2020           5
6      AFG Afghanistan 29/02/2020           5
```

```
structure(list(iso_code = c("AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", 
"AFG"), location = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), date = c("24/02/2020", 
"25/02/2020", "26/02/2020", "27/02/2020", "28/02/2020", "29/02/2020"
), total_cases = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please  provide a reproducible example of your dataset.

Comment: Your first code snippet gives me: `Warning message: 'choropleth' objects don't have these attributes: 'format'`. What exactly are you trying to do with the date? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure where this is going as 'choropleth' objects don't have a `format` attribute as your code suggests. I guess you want an animation.

To provide dates to the `frame` attribute you'll need to make them a `factor`:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

country <- structure(list(iso_code = c("AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG",
                          "AFG"), location = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan",
                          "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), date = c("24/02/2020",
                          "25/02/2020", "26/02/2020", "27/02/2020", "28/02/2020", "29/02/2020" ),
                          total_cases = seq(0, 51000000, length.out = 6)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class =
                          "data.frame")


cot_map <- country %>% select(location, date, total_cases)
cot_map$date <- as.factor(as.Date(cot_map$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))

plot_geo(cot_map,
         locationmode = "country names",
         frame = ~date) %>% 
  add_trace(locations = ~location,
            z = ~total_cases,
            zmin = 0,
            zmax = 51000000,
            color = ~total_cases) %>%
  animation_slider(
    currentvalue = list(prefix = "Date: ")
  )
```

[image: result]

PS: I'd use `max(country$total_cases)` to define `zmax`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'm still very new at all of this, so I still have tons to learn. I have no idea why I used a ```format``` attribute here, I was following a tutorial and had used ```frame``` in my project. Thanks again!